# Mutating Prototype webcomponents js

Tags: polymer

Hello I'm having mutating Prototype Error in my firefox 33.1 kindly see image below

http://i.gyazo.com/85b852e2572121d234dd374798d5d8a7.png

i also included webcomponents.js and platform.js on my html

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/mBdbvBR-YxQ

Comment: yeah that's also my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post also on google polymer group and they said that

"**That's not an error, that's a warning, and you can ignore it.**"